# OOP Associations and database access

Tags: database, oop, associations

My project has a class software and another class OS. A software may support multiple operating systems (My actual problem is much more complex).

I'm not sure how to save it in most effective way in my database. My table structure is as follows:

Table: os

```
id        name          platform
=================================
winxp     Windows XP    windows
win7      Windows 7     windows
...
```

Table: softwares

```
id        name             publisher     os
====================================================
chrome    Google Chrome    google        winxp,win7,...
ccleaner  Ccleaner         piriform      winxp,win7,...
...
```

**Is this the best way?** Will this cause any problem when programming with OOP (I use DAO approach) Or should i change it somethig like the following one :

Table: os

```
id        name          platform
=================================
winxp     Windows XP    windows
win7      Windows 7     windows
...
```

Table: softwares

```
id        name             publisher  
=====================================
chrome    Google Chrome    google      
ccleaner  Ccleaner         piriform   
...
```

Table: os_support

```
softwareid        os
======================
chrome            winxp
chrome            win7
ccleaner          winxp
ccleaner          win7
ccleaner          win8
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach is wrong - there would be redundancy in your softwares tables. 
I'm not sure what you mean by `winxp,win7...` - storing multiple values in a one cell? It's also wrong way - values should be atomic (1st normal form) - but if you mean duplicating row in software table for each operating system - there will be redundancy - like I said at the beggining.

The second approach looks much better (of course if you get rid of **os** column in **software** table).

To be sure that field/tables organization is proper, you should read about normalization. Reffer [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274985/normalize-table-to-3rd-normal-form) 3rd normal form is that what you need :)

Comment: (Edited my question-changed softwares table). winxp,win7 means the operating systems which the software supports. In the table 'software', id is the primary key.

Comment: But my database may have thousands of softwares, each software supports 5-6 operating systems. So the second approach takes much more space than the first approach.

Comment: _winxp,win7 means the operating systems which the software supports._ I know, but in the first approach you want to store these values in a one cell?

Comment: If I were you, I'd sacrifice a space for conveniency and performance. If your database is really big like u said, redundancy is not what you want. What is more, If you create indexes properly, your database would be fast. Mayby it's worth to consider additional table? I mean sth like additional operating system packs. Let's say you have Windows Pack (that contains W7, XP etc) and os_support reffers to that table.